# AWS Personalize: Send events and get recommendations for non-registered user using SessionId

Tags: amazon-web-services, recommendation-engine, sessionid

I use the "E-Commerce domain" together with the recommender "Recommended for you". But I'm pretty sure it applies also to the "Custom Domain" use-case together with the "USER_PERSONALIZATION recipe".

**Goal 1.** Make recommendations better for users which will register soon by sending events containing sessionId

**Goal 2.** Get recommendations for users which are not registered yet by sessionId

**AWS specification says:**

> For new users, recommendations will initially be only for popular items. Starting with the first event, user recommendations will be more relevant as you record events

> [AWS spec also says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/personalize-dg.pdf#page=413&zoom=100,96,105): If you recorded events for a user before they logged in (an anonymous user), you can get recommendations for this user by providing the sessionId from those events instead of a userId. For more information about recording events for anonymous users, see PutEvents operation (p. 203)

**Experiment**

1. Get recommendations for non-existing user A
2. Get recommendations for non-existing user B (they will be the same)
3. Send putEvent for non-existing user C without userId but with session ID for the product
   P1, send putEvent for user C with sessionId and userId for product
   P2. Get recommendations. After getting recommendations, we see that
   we got different results compared to user A/B
4. Send putEvent for user D and product P2. Get recommendations. Check that you get different results compared to users A/B/C. **After verification, I see that user D gets the same recommendations as user C. So it looks like sending events with sessionId but without userId do not affect recommendations**

Also, **it is not possible** to make a GetRecommendations request by sending [only sessionId parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/personalize-dg.pdf#page=413&zoom=100,96,105) according to spec, as this method doesn't use sessionId as input parameter.

Do I missing something?